# Need Help Solving this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$−1.34= \frac{x−35.7}{4.1}$$

Since $x$ is on the right-hand side of the equation, switch the sides so it is on the left-hand side of the equation.

$$0.243902439024(x−35.7)=−1.34$$

How do you get this far? it has something to do with the denominator.

Comment: Yes, $0.2439... = \frac{1}{4.1}$. Keep in mind that dividing by a number can also be thought of multiplying by the multiplicative inverse of that number.

Comment: You don't need to solve $1/4.1$.  Just multiply both sides of the equation by it.

Comment: Because $\Bbb{R}$ is a field, it *does* have inveraes.

Comment: @DonLarynx I don't think the OP is quite at the level at where they'd know about fields.

Anyway, as Carlos said, the fraction is already in a convenient form, so no need to mess with it.

Answer (score 2):

$−1.34= \displaystyle\frac{x−35.7}{4.1}$

Multiply both sides by $4.1$ to cancel the denominator:

$(4.1)(-1.34)=\displaystyle\frac{x−35.7}{4.1}(4.1) \implies (4.1)(-1.34)=x−35.7$

Now add $35.7$ to both sides to cancel the $-35.7$:

$(4.1)(-1.34)+35.7=x−35.7+35.7 \implies (4.1)(-1.34)+35.7=x$

Comment: Typos around 4.1 and .41 !

Answer (score 0):

$x-35.7=(4.1)(-1.34) \Rightarrow x=(4.1)(-1.34)+35.7 \Rightarrow x=30.206$.